# Finite Group Theory Homomorphisms/Kernels

Tags: group-theory

We've just learned Sylow's Theorem and are now starting to apply it. I understand how to approach the questions and keep using the following phrase, as it appears in our notes:

"As G is simple => the kernel is trivial => the order of G divides n!"
Just to explain this, there's a homomorphism from a group G into Sym(n).

However, I don't actually understand why either of the implications are true. Would anyone be able to help me understand it, either a hint as to what properties are used or a full answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $G$ acts on a set $S$ of cardinality $n$; then there is a homomorphism $\varphi$ induced by this action from $G$ into the symmetric group on $S$, which is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Sym}(n)$. Explicitly, we have

$$\varphi(g) = [s \mapsto s \ast g]$$

That is, the image of $g$ is the function that takes an element $s$ to wherever $g$ sends it under the action $*$. The *kernel* of this homomorphism is automatically a normal subgroup of $G$, since the kernel of *any* homomorphism is a normal subgroup (prove this!).

But $G$ is simple, and so the kernel is either the identity element or the entire group. If the action is not trivial, the kernel is the identity element, so by the first isomorphism theorem,

$$G \cong G / \{e\} = G / \ker \varphi \cong \varphi(G) \le \operatorname{Sym}(n)$$

Finally, since $|\operatorname{Sym}(n)| = n!$, Lagrange's Theorem implies that $|G| \Big| n!$.

Comment: Yes, that makes absolute perfect sense! Thank you very much. Just going to try and prove the kernel statement.

Comment: Yes, I've proved the kernel statement, so all that's left is to understand why Rho(G) <= Sym(n), but I think this is just the definition? Going to look at that now, so thank you very much for the help!

Comment: @user60126 It's because the image of a group under a homomorphism is a group. Glad I could help!

Comment: Just to clarify, should that last symbol be a "contained in" symbol rather than a "less than or equal to" symbol? If so, then I understand.

Comment: @user60126 By $\le$, I mean subgroup.

Comment: Yes, fine, that's perfect. Thank you very much. :D Sorry, not used to the notation online. In our notes, we have the "contained in" symbol for subgroup.

Comment: @user60126 You're very welcome.